# how to use looping variables to populate an array

Tags: arrays, bash

when I populate an array using explicit range value it get populated correctly using the code below:

```
arr=()
for i in {0..10}
do
    arr+=( 1 )
done
echo ${arr[@]}
```

and I got the following output [image: output] (nothing surprising)

However, when storing the range in a variable and calling it as in the code below it only shows one element:

```
range=10
arr=()
for i in {0..$range}
do
    arr+=( 1 )
done
echo ${arr[@]}
```

I got the following output [image: error output]

Comment: Make it `for i in $(seq 0 $range)` as explained in the linked question.

Comment: Do not convert text into pixels.

Comment: Read the chapter [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) in the Bash manual.

Comment: ugly solution but works: `range=10; eval "arr=( \$(printf '1%.0s ' {0..$range}) )"`

Answer (score 1):

Variable expansion does not occur before brace expansion so you only get a literal `{0..1}` as a single iterated argument.

Use the old school method instead:

```
for (( i = 0; i <= range; ++i )); do
```

- Used `<=` here because `..` is inclusive.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you decide to answer this instead of marking it as a duplicate since your explanation is also mentioned in the question I linked.

Comment: @0stone0 I didn't look at it before I answered and it's trivial enough that I can simply give a solution specific to the example in the question.